# Redefine an existing function

Tags: python, class, wxpython, subclass

I define a subclass of `PyControl` like this :

```
class MyBitmapButton(wx.PyControl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=-1, bmp=None, label='blah', pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size=(166,220), style = 0, validator = wx.DefaultValidator,
                 name = "mybitmapbutton"):
        style |= wx.BORDER_NONE 
        wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style, validator, name)
        self.myimg = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bmp, pos=(8,8), size=(150,150))
        self.mytxt = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label, (6,165))

    def Bind(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Bind(*args, **kwargs)         # infinite recursion problem ! 
        self.myimg.Bind(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mytxt.Bind(*args, **kwargs)
```

I would like to **override** the standard `Bind`, but in this definition, I need to use the **old** Bind (that was provided by `wx.PyControl`).

With this current code, I get an `infinite recusion loop` problem :

How to reuse the **old** `Bind` in the definition of the **new** `Bind` ?

Comment: The 2 answers came at the same time, with equal quality, so I really didn't know which answer to choose ? Sorry for one of the 2 answers, I gave "Accept as answer" by random !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) here, to access the superclass's version of `Bind`:

```
super(MyBitmapButton, self).Bind(*args, **kwargs)
```

or, in Python 3, simply

```
super().Bind(*args, **kwargs).
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `self.Bind(*args, **kwargs)` to:

```
super(MyBitmapButton, self).Bind(*args, **kwargs)
```

in python3 super will work without arguments:

```
super().Bind(*args, **kwargs)
```

from [`super` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or
>   sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods
>   that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that
>   used by getattr() except that the type itself is skipped.
>   ...